# Using grep with ps and column width specification

Tags: grep, zsh, ps, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to limit the column width of the `command` column when running a ps `command`, but also trying to pipe that output into a `grep` command.  However, this is not working.

This runs fine:

```
ps -eo pid,user,command:30
```

However, this:

```
ps -eo pid,user,command:30 | grep node
```

gives me this error:

```
ps: command:30: keyword not found
```

I'm actually running oh-my-zsh on a Mac in case that matters.

All help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: I don't think the first command is working either, it's just that the error scrolls off the screen. Try `ps -eo pid,user,command:30 > /dev/null` to see only output sent to `stderr`. The documentation for `ps` on macOS (`man ps`) doesn't appear to mention support for width control with `-o`.

Comment: That command also yields `ps: command:30: keyword not found`.

Comment: That is as expected - looks like the old version of `ps` on macOS does not support the `:30` modifier. The output looks very different when it is removed, i.e. with `ps -eo pid,user,command`. Apparently [there isn't a way to install a newer version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187783/can-i-use-gnu-ps-on-os-x) of `ps`, but the answer below from @Vilinkameni appears to have some good workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming sed supporting `-E`, limiting `command` to 30 characters:

```
ps -eo pid,user,command |
sed -E 's/^( +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +)(.{30}).*$/\1\2/g'
```

using awk, `pid` column formatted to width 6 (assuming the pid will have at most 6 digits), `user` column formatted to width 10, `command` to 30:

```
ps -eo pid,user,command |
awk '{
        line=$0;
        sub(/^ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +/, "", line);
        printf("%6s %s%*s %s\n", $1, substr($2, 0, 10),
                length($2) <= 10 ? 10-length($2) : 0, " ",
                substr(line, 0, 30));
}'
```

Comment: The second command here with `awk` is pretty close, but it prints the pid and user columns twice.  Also, how do I limit the search results to those which only include `node` in the `command`, as was my original intent with the `grep node` portion in my question?

Comment: @risingTide I can't reproduce the issue you describe. On my system (Alpine Linux 3.18, ps from procps-ng-4.0.4-r0, awk is gawk-5.2.2-r0) the output contains no duplicate columns. You can pipe the entire pipeline with ps and awk further into grep, or you could add an `if ($3 ~ ".*node.*") { ... }` inside the awk script.

Comment: Odd that it duplicates the first 2 columns for me!  However, I was able to pipe the whole thing into grep and that worked.  Thank you.